# How to calculate Over-Provisioning on an SSD - Which Method do you use?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

**QUESTION SUMMARY:**  Is overprovisioning based on a percentage of the original user accessible physical space availble (METHOD #1)   OR is it based on unallocated space divided by allocated space (METHOD #2).

I've **attempted to set 30%** Over-provisioning on my SSD.    In doing so, after further research it seems as though I've **actually (maybe?) configured 42%** Over-provisioning **instead**.

**GOAL:  30%   Over-provisioning**

Here are my calculations:

**METHOD #1)**

Note: I've found numerous forums and documentation that clearly indicates something along the lines of "Just leave 30% unallocated at the end of the SSD".

512 GB  * 0.3  =  **153.6 GB**   <--- this amount of 30% is what I left unallocated at the end of the drive.

So my user space is  (512 GB - 153.6 GB) = 358.4 GB  <--- this amount is what I can use to store my files.

To verify the numbers:   **153.6 GB**  /  512 GB  =  0.3  =  30%

In Summary:

Available space is   **358.4 GB**
Unallocated (Overprovisioned) space is **153.6 GB**.

In my previous understanding THIS (method above) is 30% Overprovisioning  (153.6 GB / **512 GB**) = 30%.

However, as you can see **below** apparently it's 42% overprovisioning instead (153.6 GB / **358.4 GB**) = 42.9%.

**METHOD #2)**

However these links seem to indicate I wrongly calculated 30% Overprovisioning.
LINK #1:  http://www.kingston.com/us/ssd/overprovisioning and 
LINK #2  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification

The formula here:

(PhysicalCapacity - UserCapacity) / UserCapacity =  over-provision

Using the forumla and punching in these values:

PhysicalCapacity = **512GB**
UserCapacity = **358.4GB**

(512 GB  -  358.4 GB) / **358.4 GB** =

(**153.6 GB** ) / **358.4 GB** = 0.428571429 = 42.9%

**Question summary:**

- Is Overprovisioning calculated as a percentage of the TOTAL available drive size from the manufacturer?

**OR -**

- Is it a percentage of unused space relative to the available space AFTER you set your overprovisioned space.

The way I see official documentation written (such as the kingston link above) seems to favor Method #2 but the way it's discussed in forums it seems to favor Method #1.

How do you guys prefer to calculate Overprovisioning (as defined as an amount of unallocated space at the end of the drive).

NOTE:  This forum post seems to support Method #1 as one of many examples I've found on the forums  http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/over-provisioning-in-samsung-magician-software.738380/    (second post on that page).

Comment: It's clear from the Kingston document that they mean overprovisioning to refer to the difference between the physical memory installed in the device and the logical size of the SSD presented to the operating system. There is no need to waste the space you have paid for; the manufacturer has already done it for you.

Comment: Well, I understand what you mean regarding "the manufacturer has already done it for you";  the reality is end-user (Level 3) Overprovisioning is commonly done to boost performance.    Anandtech (and others) has a number of graphs, etc discussing a 25% overprovisioning improving performance considerably   LINK: http://www.anandtech.com/show/8216/samsung-ssd-850-pro-128gb-256gb-1tb-review-enter-the-3d-era/7    I researched 30% as a "sweet spot".   Again, in doing so I may have inadvertently OP'd 42.9% instead of 30%.   Which is (maybe) even better at an even higher unnecessary space cost.

Comment: Also, this Graphic link from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Over-provisioning_on_an_SSD.png  discusses the  Level 1, 2, 3 Overprovisioning.   L3 Overprovisioning is defined as "unused space" (in the context of potentially usable and part of a file system) but also is defined as simply unallocated space at the end of the drive.   I post this because I've encountered many that don't know Overprovisioning is segmented out into 3 levels of definition....